# GitLab API not setting labels and assignee_ids

Tags: gitlab

**Update**: After some additional testing, it appears that the api user must be an admin to change the label and assign users. Is there any reason why that is?

**Question**:
I’m working with GitLab 12.5, and posting a new issue through the API works with the exception that labels and assignee_ids are ignored. I’m writing utility to migrate bugzilla bugs (with attachments) to GitLab. (**side note: if you know of any way to set the author of the issue and notes/comments please let me know. Right now the author for each issue/note is a utility account I’ve created to do this automation**)

Here is my `POST` body:

```
  {
    title: 'Verify entries',
    description: '\n' +
      '*Creation Date*: `2017-03-31T14:24:09Z`  \n' +
      '*Priority*: `Normal`  \n' +
      '*Severity*: `enhancement`  \n',
    labels: 'confirmed,enhancement,priority::medium,',
    created_at: '2017-03-31T14:24:09Z',
    assignee_ids: [ '1' ]
  }
```

I even tried changing the type of those fields:

```
  {
    title: 'Verify entries',
    description: '\n' +
      '*Creation Date*: `2017-03-31T14:24:09Z`  \n' +
      '*Priority*: `Normal`  \n' +
      '*Severity*: `enhancement`  \n',
    labels: [ 'confirmed', 'enhancement', 'priority::medium' ],
    created_at: '2017-03-31T14:24:09Z',
    assignee_ids: [ 1 ]
  }
```

This is the response I get:

```
{
  id: 284,
  iid: 97,
  project_id: 2,
  title: 'Verify entries',
  description: '\n' +
    '**Creation Date**: `2017-03-31T14:24:09Z`  \n' +
    '**Priority**: `Normal`  \n' +
    '**Severity**: `enhancement`  \n',
  state: 'opened',
  created_at: '2019-12-15T01:45:56.382Z',
  updated_at: '2019-12-15T01:45:56.382Z',
  closed_at: null,
  closed_by: null,
  labels: [],
  milestone: null,
  assignees: [],
  author: {
    id: 16,
    name: 'automation',
    username: 'automation',
    state: 'active',
    avatar_url: 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2a9d2f23664aa7a31ff6330094ec3854?s=80&d=identicon',
    web_url: 'http://myaddress/automation'
  },
  assignee: null,
  user_notes_count: 0,
  merge_requests_count: 0,
  upvotes: 0,
  downvotes: 0,
  due_date: null,
  confidential: false,
  discussion_locked: null,
  web_url: 'http://myaddress/products/myproject/issues/97',
  time_stats: {
    time_estimate: 0,
    total_time_spent: 0,
    human_time_estimate: null,
    human_total_time_spent: null
  },
  task_completion_status: { count: 0, completed_count: 0 },
  has_tasks: false,
  _links: {
    self: 'http://myaddress/api/v4/projects/2/issues/97',
    notes: 'http://myaddress/api/v4/projects/2/issues/97/notes',
    award_emoji: 'http://myaddress/api/v4/projects/2/issues/97/award_emoji',
    project: 'http://myaddress/api/v4/projects/2'
  },
  subscribed: true
}
```

I verified that the labels and user id do exist.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you add the response you're getting from GitLab?

Comment: Update my question.  See both **Update** and the response appended to the initial question.

Comment: What's the permission for your "account you’ve created to do this automation"? `Guest`? `Reporter`? `Developer`? etc...

Comment: Looks like a guest user.  I will change that if I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your API user has `Guest` permission.
You can see in [GitLab's documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html) that in order to assign or label issue you need to be `Reporter` or above.

Comment: it's strange that gitlab allow a guest to post an issue, even if it did fail to apply labels and attachments.